# How to Use Oracle in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I need to use Oracle with Asp.net. Kindly Suggest me for Which Components i need to download to Use Oracle with Asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) which is Oracle's solution to connect .net applications to the Oracle world.

It ships with a membership provider for ASP.net and an entity framework implementation for Oracle and is integrated in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html

This article will provide you with a couple of different ways to use Oracle with .net. Including utilizing Oracle with .net's own ORM Entity Framework.

http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx
NHibernate is another ORM that provides a provider for connecting to Oracle.